# Exec format error while creating mongo db startup init.d script on Redhat 7

Tags: linux, redhat, mongodb, systemd

I had followed the [link](http://sysadminhub.blogspot.in/2013/12/mongo-db-startup-initd-script-on.html) for adding mongod as linux service.
after server restart, the mongod server is not restarted.

/etc/rc.d/init.d/mongod file content:

```
                #!/bin/bash
            #
            # mongodb     Startup script for the mongodb server
            #
            # chkconfig: - 64 36
            # description: MongoDB Database Server
            #
            # processname: mongodb
            #

            # Source function library
            . /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

            if [ -f /etc/sysconfig/mongodb ]; then
                    . /etc/sysconfig/mongodb
            fi

            prog="mongod"
            mongod="/usr/bin/mongod"
            mongodb_user="myUserAdmin"
            RETVAL=0

            start() {
                    echo -n $"Starting $prog: "
                    #daemon $mongod "--fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log --logappend 2>&1 >>/var/log/mongodb.log"
                    daemon --user=$mongodb_user $mongod "--config /etc/mongodb.conf"
                    RETVAL=$?
                    echo
                    [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && touch /var/lock/subsys/$prog
                    return $RETVAL
            }

            stop() {
                    echo -n $"Stopping $prog: "
                    killproc $prog
                    RETVAL=$?
                    echo
                    [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && rm -f /var/lock/subsys/$prog
                    return $RETVAL
            }
            reload() {
                    echo -n $"Reloading $prog: "
                    killproc $prog -HUP
                    RETVAL=$?
                    echo
                    return $RETVAL
            }

            case "$1" in
                    start)
                            start
                            ;;
                    stop)
                            stop
                            ;;
                    restart)
                            stop
                            start
                            ;;
                    condrestart)
                            if [ -f /var/lock/subsys/$prog ]; then
                                    stop
                                    start
                            fi
                            ;;
                    reload)
                            reload
                            ;;
                    status)
                            status $mongod
                            RETVAL=$?
                            ;;
                    *)
                            echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|condrestart|reload|status}"
                            RETVAL=1
            esac

            exit $RETVAL
```

by referring the /var/log/messages

the error showing  is

```
> Mar  4 09:04:44 redhat7 systemd: Starting SYSV: MongoDB Database Server...
Mar  4 09:04:44 redhat7 systemd: Failed at step EXEC spawning /etc/rc.d/init.d/mongod: Exec format error
Mar  4 09:04:44 redhat7 systemd: mongod.service: control process exited, code=exited status=203
Mar  4 09:04:44 redhat7 systemd: Failed to start SYSV: MongoDB Database Server.
Mar  4 09:04:44 redhat7 systemd: Unit mongod.service entered failed state.
Mar  4 09:04:44 redhat7 systemd: mongod.service failed.
```

please help me.

Comment: Add the contents of `/etc/rc.d/init.d/mongod` to the question.

Comment: Assuming this is not a copy&paste error, the problem with the contents of `/etc/rc.d/init.d/mongod` is the extra spaces at the beginning of the file. The first two bytes should be `#!`, so that systemd knows how to execute it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly not the answer you want, but you might consider a slightly different approach.

Your instructions date from 2013, and relate to the pre-systemd RedHat. 
You have RedHat 7, which (AFAIK) has systemd, and I would recommend you use it, rather than use an init script.

Although I am surprised you don't have a suitable script dropped into place when you installed mongo, I think it might make sense to consider using mongo's own service unit for RPM based systems (taken from https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/rpm/mongod.service):

```
[Unit]
Description=High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
After=network.target
Documentation=https://docs.mongodb.org/manual

[Service]
User=mongod
Group=mongod
Environment="OPTIONS=--quiet -f /etc/mongod.conf"
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod $OPTIONS run
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/mongodb
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown mongod:mongod /var/run/mongodb
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chmod 0755 /var/run/mongodb
PermissionsStartOnly=true
PIDFile=/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
# file size
LimitFSIZE=infinity
# cpu time
LimitCPU=infinity
# virtual memory size
LimitAS=infinity
# open files
LimitNOFILE=64000
# processes/threads
LimitNPROC=64000
# total threads (user+kernel)
TasksMax=infinity
TasksAccounting=false
# Recommended limits for for mongod as specified in
# http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/ulimit/#recommended-settings

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

You would want to put that into /etc/systemd/system/mongod.service, and possibly disable your init script.

Comment: disabled the init script and used this method...   after restart the log is                  `   ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 1
Mar  6 07:12:40 redhat7 systemd: mongod.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar  6 07:12:40 redhat7 systemd: Unit mongod.service entered failed state.
Mar  6 07:12:40 redhat7 systemd: mongod.service failed. `

Comment: You might want to try running the startup command manually, and debugging that way: `sudo -u mongod /usr/bin/mongod  -f /etc/mongod.conf`. If you need help with interpreting it, then please post the (relevant) output

Comment: tested in command line with  `sudo -u mongod /usr/bin/mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf `   showing the same error ouput!!!

Comment: Ok - could you share (some of) that output? Is there some other logging you could check, too? It might also be useful to add `-v` to the command line, and see if that show  anything interesting

Comment: the error output  `[root@redhat7 ~]# sudo -u mongod /usr/bin/mongod -v  -f /etc/mongod1.conf
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 2260
ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 1`   is it any permission issue?

Comment: Based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28591101/starting-mongod-fork-error-child-process-failed-exited-with-error-number-1#29583510, possibly - that question and its answers seem to be what you need next/now

Comment: after adding the ` --smallFiles` the mongod started succesfully from command line. but after reboot, error log shows the same error.